# Should I list a completely different profession in my technical resume?

Tags: resume, career-switch, tech-industry

I was a cook for 5 years but I switched jobs and now I'm a web developer. Should I put this information in my resume along with my experience in tech companies while searching for a job as a web developer?

Comment: have you read some of these threads? https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=list+all+jobs Consensus seems to be "show continuous employment, highlight relevant jobs"

Comment: As mentioned in some comments, can you clarify whether leaving out this experience will have a gap in your resume? Means, did you start with something, then took the role of a cook and then switched to IT? Or is it cook to IT - directly?

Comment: I have the same issue and overcome it by adding my cooking experience in an additional interests section, along with hobbies and certificates/publications outside of my main degree (maths)

Comment: I think an answer to this would depend on location - in some places brevity is important and you only list relevant experience, in others you're expected to list everything and any gaps would be viewed with suspicion.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I suggest that you wrote down your cook experience and emphasize what you learn that you can use in your next position.

We hired some candidates as a Junior Developer in past companies where I work that they were Cook for multiples years. They emphasize in their resume that they learn soft skills like team communication, planning, etc. because they are crucial in kitchen rush moments.

I can feel every day in the development world a backslash when the communication is not adequate on a decision or when a developer decides to go solo on an underestimated task. So I feel those skills are essential for a developer position.

I propose you drop the cook position in your resume when you will acquire more experience in the development field.

Comment: Also the importance of preparation when you anticipate stress, organisational skills and making do with what you have. All important habits!

Answer (score 9):

Briefly mention that you were a cook but other than that do not go into detail unless you have your resume is looking bare then I suggest you talk about it just to show that you have had a professional career and not a 5 year break.

Otherwise just keep your resume relevant to the jobs you are applying for.

Answer (score 4):

That really depends.    Did you just recently change fields?   Are you fresh out of college?

A potential employer may want to see the past 10 years of employment experience.   If you're 22 and you've been in IT for a few years, it's not a big deal.   If you're 32 and you've been a web developer for 2 years, they're going to want to know what you  were doing before then. It doesn't have to have a prominent place on the resume, but it's not a bad idea to have a single line saying "Fry Cook, 2012-2017" with the name of the restaurant.

I'd also suggest that even as a guy fresh out of college, five years in a job is an accomplishment.  Heck, as an adult, five years in a job demonstrates longevity.    It shows a potential employer that you won't jump ship after 6 months for a petty reason.

Comment: `It shows a potential employer that you won't jump ship after 6 months for a petty reason.` I don't think in IT it matters much, people can (and will) eventually jump ships, if they are not treated properly. Whether they did not do that previously matters very little. and the definition of "petty" - depends.

Comment: @SouravGhosh yes and no.  After working in IT for about 5-6 years I actually was asked that question in an interview.  I had moved every year or so and they wanted to know if they hired me, would I stick around?  Contrast that with my brother-in-law, who has been at the same company for 25 years.    He is not getting paid what he could, but he would rather stay at the same company.